# How to connect data base and insert data

Tags: c#

I get an error about `ExecuteNonquery is not initialized`.

And I think may be connecting to the database wrong because the `MessageBox`is not appearing before executing the system.

```
//Server Connection
private void ServerConnect()
{

    string ConnString;
    ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=PLAN.accdb";
    TConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
    TConn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("You Are Connected.");
}

//ADD MEMOS
private void GetMemoList()
{

    string query;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    query = "SELECT MEMOS_ID,DATE,TIME,MEMOS FROM TBLMEMOS ORDER BY DATE ASC";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, TConn);
    da.Fill(ds);
    this.dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}

private void AddMemo(string MemoDate, string MemoTime, string Memos)
{

    string acc;
    acc = "INSERT INTO TBLMEMOS (DATE,TIME,MEMOS) VALUES ('" + MemoDate + "','" + MemoTime + "','" + Memos + "')";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = acc;
    cmd.Connection = TConn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

private void btnAddMemos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AddMemo(this.dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), this.dtpTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(), this.txtInfo.Text.Trim());
    GetMemoList();
    txtInfo.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You're creating and opening the connection in the method `ServerConnect`.  Unless `TConn` is a global variable *and* you call the ServerConnect method before any other methods, your `OleDbCommand` will not have an open connection to execute against.

Comment: Can you help me how to connect the Server connection im beginner in Connecting database sir thank you

Comment: Sir I got it thanks But i got another Error "No Value Give For one or more required in parameters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parameters like this.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.Char).Value = MemoDate ;
```

Comment: +1 from me, you do not need to worry if some one review it, or mark it as answer. There are a lot of answers that you may give like that.